# how to directly read a vector data from unmanaged in managed code using it's pointer

Tags: c#, c++, memory

I have a console c++ application creates a vector and assign data to it :

```
vector<char> demo_vector_1 = {
        0x54, 0x48, 0x49, 0x53, 0x20, 0x49, 0x53, 0x20, 0x44, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x4F,
        0x20, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x41
};
```

No I have a managed dll with a exported function :

```
[DllExport]
 static public void ReadThisVector(IntPtr v_ptr,long datasize)
        {
           //// Data processing ...
        }
```

then I call this function in c++ and pass the vector data pointer to my C# code :

```
ReadThisVector((long)&demo_vector_1[0], demo_vector_1.size());
```

I printed out pointer of vector both in c++ and c# and they match.

Now I need to access and ready some parts of that vector directly from C# code.
I tried to use ReadProcessMemory but I get Access Violation error.

How can I read vector data directly to a buffer byte array or even better C# List ?
I don't want to copy anything , just direct access , because my data size will be huge.

c# dll is loaded in console and same process of unmanaged process , so it should access to its memory but how ?

Do I pass the vector pointer in a proper way ?

**NOTE:** I don't want to use memory mapped files.

Comment: @MickyD well , good question , My main reason is speed and security. btw I solved the problem :D

Comment: Excellent!  Feel free to post it as an answer and if no other better answers come along, you can accept your own.  Happy New Year! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure you got your data types right. The code you have now works for 64-bit builds, fails in 32-bit builds. Here‘s one way to fix:

```
[DllExport]
static public void ReadThisVector( IntPtr v_ptr, uint datasize )
// C++
ReadThisVector( demo_vector_1.data(), (uint32_t)demo_vector_1.size() );
```

Now, on your question — you can call [Marshal.ReadByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.readbyte?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_ReadByte_System_IntPtr_System_Int32_) for that.

Or, if you have modern .NET and you OK with unsafe code, you can [create a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlyspan-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_ReadOnlySpan_1__ctor_System_Void__System_Int32_) from your 2 values. If you need that data for IO, modern .NET has stuff like `Stream.Write(ReadOnlySpan<byte>)` i.e. streams can write directly from unmanaged buffers without making copies.

Unfortunately, there’s no way to directly cast unmanaged memory into C# array or list. You either need to copy, or change APIs from arrays/lists into spans/pointers.

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution just 2 minutes after posting my question , my process is 64bit but the problem was the bad DllImport of ReadProcessMemory but your answer gave me a better solution to achieve that , **Marshal.ReadByte**  was the exact thing  I was looking for , answer accepted.

Comment: @J.Mcgill Good. Happy new year, BTW.